# Why does vector.emplace() require item to be MoveAssignable?

Tags: c++, vector

From [en.cppreference.com on vector.emplace():](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace)

> T (the container's element type) must meet the requirements of
>   MoveAssignable, MoveInsertable and EmplaceConstructible.

emplace_back() however does not require T to be MoveAssignable.

My problem is I have a item like this -

```
class Node
{
public:
    ...

    const std::string mName;
    const AABB mLocalAABB;
    const Mat4 mLocalTransform;
}
```

Which is not MoveAssignable due to having const-members.

Why can't emplace() just create the item in-place like emplace_back()?

*It might be off-topic but ultimately the reason I want to use emplace() over  emplace_back() is that all the space in vector has been reserved() in advance and I want to emplace the items back-to-front. Using emplace_back() and then std::reverse() does not work as it also needs the item to be MoveAssignable.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vector::emplace` can place items at arbitrary locations in the vector. In order to do this, it needs to move all the objects starting from the insertion point back by 1 space, so as to make room for the new element. It moves them with the move assignment operator, hence the requirement to be move assignable.

Comment: *"It moves them with the move assignment operator, hence..."* - not necessarily... counter-intuitively, the Move Assignable requirement just means the `v[n + 1] = v[n];` assignment's supported, whether by move assignment operator or "copy" assignment operator.

Comment: @TonyD: You mean `v[n + 1] = std::move(v[n])`, right? Because how could `v[n + 1] = v[n];` ever be move assignment? The standard lists the required expression as `t = rv`, where `t` is a modifiable L-value of type T, and `rv` is an R-value of type T. I agree though, that doesn't necessarily mean that the object will be move assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you pass `end()` as the position, `emplace` is putting the object in a position where there already is another object. This is performed by moving the old object to the next position and then move-assign the new object to the (now empty) old object.

You would like the old object to be destructed and a new created in its place, but that would be problematic if the construction failed with an exception. The vector would then have a hole in it, and fail one of its invariants.